# Debian/Kali – Problem with writing to /etc/resolv.conf

Tags: kali-linux, resolv.conf

I want to connect to a public DNS Server (in this case Google's) by modifying the `/etc/resolv.conf` (which is automatically generated by NetworkManager). If I edit the content of the file via `gedit /etc/resolv.conf` to

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

(which are the IPs of Google's public DNS server), everything works fine and I do not even have DNS leaks, but if I run my Script:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" > /etc/resolv.conf
echo "nameserver 8.8.4.4" >> /etc/resolv.conf
```

It does not work and I have no Internet-Connection at all.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what's showing, an error message maybe, ... also make sure your script is executable.

Comment: There is no error message, the script changes the `resolv.conf` like I want to the same thing I do via `gedit`, I just do not have an internet connection afterwards...:(

Comment: Could you please post the output of following commands : `ifconfig -a` and `netstat -rn`

Comment: It would be useful to [edit] your question to show the result of `cat /etc/resolv.conf` when it's working before you run your script and after your script has run (when it's broken).

Comment: When you "_have no Internet Connection_" do you really mean that? What is then the result of running `ping -c4 8.8.8.8`? If you get no result please post the output of `netstat -rn`. But [add these answers to your question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/342875/edit); do not put them here in comments.

Answer (score 1):

If your /etc/resolv.conf is autogenerated by NetworkManager, it will be overwritten at many network events like DHCP-Requests. This is done by the resolvconf package. See `man resolvconf` (head and tail files) for persistent change of the resolv.conf.